# Recommended email sending languages

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, html

I've been searching the web for answers to my question and still no clear answers. 
I'm trying do develop an HTML5(+CSS3+JavaScript) mobile application that has the capability of sending the values of text boxes or from the values of websql database. But I don't clearly see what is the best language to use.

Can anyone give recommendation for me to what language to be used like JSON or AJAX?
Any answers would be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: JSON is a markup language, and AJAX is a technique (closely bound to JavaScript).

Comment: If you're developing in JavaScript, you have chosen your language already, why do you ask? You just need an environment that allows you to communicate with WebSQL (like a browser) or that lets you send emails (like Node.js)

Answer (score 2):

You need a ***backend*** to receive your ajax call, that backend (read: server application) would then be responsible for sending the email.

Comment: On a sidenote: flash would be able to do SMTP without a dedicated server backend, but it would still require a socket policy file to be allowed to do so ( see "actionscript SMTPMailer" http://www.bytearray.org/?p=27 )